# Extension of solutions of PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be an open set such that $\mathbf{0} \in \Omega$. Let $A := \Omega \setminus (\{0\}\times \mathbb{R})$, that is, $A$ is $\Omega$ with the $y$-axis removed.

Let $F: (A\cup \{\mathbf{0}\})\times\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $F$ is real analytic on the open set $A \times \mathbb{R}^5$. Let us consider the partial differential equation on the set $A$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial y^2} = F(x,y,\varphi, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x\partial y}, \frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^2}) $$

with the initial conditions

$$ \varphi(x,0) = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}(x,0) = 0 $$

By Cauchy-Kovalevskaya this PDE has a solution in an open neighborhood of the $x$-axis inside the set $A$. Assume that the solution exists in all of $A$ and $F:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $D = A \times \mathbb{R}^{5} \subset \mathbb{R}^{7}$. Furthermore assume that $F$ exists when $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Under what circumstances is it possible to extend this solution to a full neighbourhood of $\mathbf{0}$ ?

Comment: to the first question: yes I am assuming that I remove the $y-$Axis. second question: Well $F$ is real analytic, but if one restricts all the data to the point $0$, then $F$ does exists there.

Comment: so my question is: is it possible to extend it somehow to the y-axis?

Comment: but i do not know if the equation makes sense everywhere. does it make sense ?

Comment: well I meant that $F$ is defined on the whole real axis, i.e. the $x$-axis. Can one then extend it to the $y$-axis?

Comment: ok i see. So $D$ has the form: $D=(A \cup \{ 0\}) \times \mathbb{R}^{5} \subset \mathbb{R}^{7}$. Thus $F:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also real-analytic.

Comment: How do you interpret real analyticity at $\{0\}$? This point is not in the interior of $D$.

Comment: Okay, if $F$ is not defined along the $y$ axis, what do you mean by "extend a solution"? Do you actually mean "extend the solution to a real analytic function on a full neighborhood of the origin"?

Comment: BTW, instead of responding to my comments piecemeal, what you should be doing is to edit all this clarifications into your original question. I've done so for a large number of your comments. But please do it yourself from now on.

Comment: I actually do not mean analyticity at $\{0\}$. What I actually wanted to say is that $F$ does exists in the point $0$. I mean for $x=0,y=0$. Now I just want to know if the solution exists in a neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: I have made the changes in my question. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: or does anybody have an idea?